# Can't find the ASP.NET Configuration tab in the Website menu in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm going crazy because I can't find the ASP.NET configuration tab in Visual Studio 2017.
I'm following Microsofts ASP.NET tutorial on how to create a login page with members. 
[This is what the tutorial tells me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5nlF.png)

[And this is what my menu looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doEfx.png)

Please help me. I've been looking after it for an hour now without any luck.

[Link to the relevant chapter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx#Configuring%20Membership)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This menu item was removed some time ago (VS2013 or VS2015, I can't remember).  It's unfortunate that the documentation hasn't been updated.

Anyway, you should check out ASP.NET Identity instead.  It's now preferred over the old Membership provider model you're looking at.  Give it a go at [asp.net/identity](http://asp.net/identity)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx) page, yes? If you click the other versions link, you can see its meant for Visual Studio 2010.  Nice of them to make that obvious, eh?  Anywho, if you want built in authentication you can still use it, you just have to pick the Individual Accounts option for authentication when creating an account.  This is not using the old school Membership Provider though, as that is outdated.  Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7eb22ec0-b566-4e32-bf4c-cd51f4fe1fa6/trying-to-find-aspnet-configuration-in-vs-community-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral#97bf6e70-3b30-4c63-975c-aa4c782df2a3).

If you still really really want the old MembershipProvider, I would suggest just downloading Visual Studio 2010 from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/#visual-studio-2010) and going to town.  Enjoy!